# Trying to get a page to display a certain way

Tags: php, asp.net, http, www-mechanize

I have a link from an MLS system, it defaults to a certain view, but you are able to click a down arrow and select a new view. I want to create a link that will show that view if this is possible? I tried to Inspect element and take part of that link but it didnt work. Here is the regular link

> http://mfr.mlsmatrix.com/DE.asp?ID=13808753531

and when I inspected the display as: split map with details it gets me

> mfr.mlsmatrix.com/Matrix/public/css/portal?v=7WfyuM1FPyZ1CtiEM_wPpAHxTIO3TGOZH1aofu3oswk1

So i tried to take that view part and create

> mfr.mlsmatrix.com/DE.asp?ID=13808753531?v=7WfyuM1FPyZ1CtiEM_wPpAHxTIO3TGOZH1aofu3oswk1

and even

> http://mfr.mlsmatrix.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?ID=13808753531?v=7WfyuM1FPyZ1CtiEM_wPpAHxTIO3TGOZH1aofu3oswk1

But this obviously didn't work. I am a PHP noob. Wondering if it is possible, would help me and my client out SO MUCH if this can be done. I did at least try, but it is as far as my capabilities go.

thank you

Comment: The reason it's difficult is that the you're not supposed to scrape/iframe it. Get your client to talk to their brokerage or the MLS board to get proper RETS access. If the board finds your client's site with unauthorized data [and they will] they can be penalized by the board.

Comment: DOnt know what you are talking about, its not iframed, the first link is the one created directly from the MLS

Comment: Curious what you mean by unauthorized data. We created this search directly in his mlsmatrix and set up an email to send this list to customers

Comment: The company I work for maintains websites for many realtors and brokerages and each site must pass a compliance audit to ensure that, among other things, the realtor is authorized to use MLS data and that the website itself meets the criteria set out by the MLS board. If a realtor is found to be making unauthorized use of MLS data the board may choose to penalize the realtor. MFR in particular can be a bit on the strict side. Your client really should consult with the board on this and get you some RETS credentials.

Comment: thanks I'll look into that. I found other people using these types of links on craigslist, facebook, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending the parameters correctly.  The first param is sent with a ? prefix, all subsequent param/value pairs are separated by &, like so:

`http://mfr.mlsmatrix.com/Matrix/Public/Portal.aspx?ID=13808753531&v=7WfyuM1FPyZ1CtiEM_wPpAHxTIO3TGOZH1aofu3oswk1`

But you really should be interacting via API instead of trying to scrape.

Comment: Again Im not sure why people are saying scraped. This is the list that is created from the MLS system. It looks like this (which is ugly).
Not sure how to interact with the matrix (or if you can) with an API

Comment: You should see if they have RETS or IDX, etc. feeds available to you (or your client).  That would give you much more direct access to the data and allow you to do much, much more with it.  But in the meantime, the URL I corrected in my answer does work :-)

Comment: Try that link in an incognito window, it didnt work for me. Once you change the display yourself it will always show that way. but when I open your link in incognito, it still displays as just a list